# What can a spellcaster do to protect against a thunderstone?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, hearing

As a low-level spellcaster, what can be done to counter the deafness from a thunderstone? Either by protecting against deafness, circumventing or removing the effect.

Comment: Can you clarify in your question what you mean by *low-level*? For example, the game changes massively between 1st and 2nd levels, so if you like the first third of the levels, 1st through 7th say, answers might focus more on the post-1st situation, while if you mean 1st level or 1st through 3rd or something, then the 1st-level situation becomes much more significant.

Comment: While there are a few ways to protect against a thunderstone (per your title), the body of your question asks how to counter the deafness from a thunderstone, which is a different question. Which of those two questions do you want us to answer?

Comment: @Cellion I think the question is pretty clear that any way to avoid suffering from deafness when an enemy throws a thunderstone, whether that be by somehow blocking or redirecting the attack or protecting yourself against deafness, would answer the question. Which *could* be kind of broad, except I don’t really think there are a *lot* of options here.

Comment: @KRyan with low level I was thinking of 1st-2nd level

Comment: but could be higher to add more options. Yes anyway to either avoid the attack, or remove the effect of deafness. I will update the question later to reflect the that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few different ways to either protect yourself from a thunderstone or ignore its effects:

[Earplugs](https://www.aonprd.com/EquipmentMiscDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Earplugs) - Grant a +2 bonus on your save against the thunderstone's effect, and are inexpensive enough for any low-level character.

[Forced Quiet](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Forced%20Quiet) - This spell can we cast on someone to protect them against sonic effects, like those of a thunderstone. It grants them +2 on their save, stacking with earplugs.

[Remove Blindness/Deafness](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Remove%20Blindness/Deafness) - If you're already deafened, this 3rd level spell (cast by a friendly caster or from a scroll) will clear it without waiting out the full hour.

Spells without verbal components are not affected by being deaf, including the deafness induced by a thunderstone. If you expect to be deaf, you can use the [Silent Spell metamagic](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Silent%20Spell) to remove verbal components from your spells. Alternatively, the [Deaf curse Oracle](https://www.aonprd.com/OracleCurses.aspx) gets Silent spell for free on every spell they cast.

Comment: +1 good answer, but for a low-level spellcaster I think the *forced quiet* or *remove deafness* spells are more expensive than they are worth.  Better to take the 20% spell failure chance from being deaf than to spend spells or scrolls on these preventative measures.

Comment: @DanB That would be a very tough call. Spell slots are at a dire premium for low-level spellcasters, no question, but *actions in combat* are at a dire premium *always, for everyone*. If you are already deaf and expecting to go into a fight, saving a spell slot by refusing to cast *remove blindness/deafness* could easily get you killed. At least with the spell slot burned, you can still do *something* with your turn, and plan knowing you won’t have that slot. If you try to cast something else while deaf, you have a 20% chance of doing nothing at all.

Answer (score 2):

As Cellion suggests, if you're worried about this attack, you could wear earplugs.  This item gives +2 to your save against sonic effects but -5 to hearing-based perception checks.

Other than that, for a low-level spellcaster, you shouldn't spend resources defending against this attack.  This attack inflicts on you a 20% spell failure chance for an hour.  If the combat lasts five rounds and then you can rest for an hour, then on average you will lose only one spell from being deafened, and you might not even lose that if you fail your save.

It's not worth it to prepare silent spells, to spend a spell slot on *forced quiet* as a precaution, or to use a third-level spell scroll on *remove deafness*.  Just be glad that the enemy didn't do something more effective with their ranged attack.

Comment: In the end I choose to accept the answer by Cellion, as it most directly answer the question I asked. But the question I probably should have asked, is what a spellcaster should do to prepare against it, in which case I agree with you reasoning that it is not worth it. I guess I was just alarmed when I saw the duration of an hour, and erroneously thought of that as 600 rounds of combat.